# CRASH BILLSERVICE UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-billing, android-billing, validate-request

everybody. 
I got something error when update our app to play store. 
I tested ok but when user play, they send alot of crash to google service. 
Hope you can help me to know what happen. Thank you.

```
<i>java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [pool-4-thread-1]
Unity version     : 5.6.0f3
Device model      : samsung SM-G900V
Device fingerprint: Verizon/kltevzw/kltevzw:6.0.1/MMB29M/G900VVRU2DQF2:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent (ContextImpl.java:1297)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1421)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService (ContextImpl.java:1399)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService (ContextWrapper.java:632)
  at com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.BillingServiceManager.bindToGooglePlayService (BillingServiceManager.java:104)
  at com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.BillingServiceManager$2.run (BillingServiceManager.java:136)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)`enter code here`
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)</i>
```